# Height of binary tree recursively

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-tree

I get the correct height for all cases expect for when it is an empty binary tree. The size should be zero, but I get 1. I try changing the return after the if statement (get rid of the +1) but that just messes up every other case.

```
int BTree::recursive_height_helper(BSTNode *n) {

    int rHeight = 0;
    int lHeight = 0;

    if(n->right == NULL || n->left == NULL) return rHeight+lHeight+1;
    rHeight += recursive_height_helper(n->right);
    lHeight += recursive_height_helper(n->left);

     return rHeight+lHeight+1;
}
```

Comment: Unless I misunderstand how your function is supposed to work, you pass in a root node,do you not? In which case the height cannot be less than 1, as that root node is the entire tree. If you passed in a null pointer, which would be empty, your function would fail. If you handle the case of a null pointer, then you can pass in a truly empty tree, and get 0 back. I may be misunderstanding your situation - in which case, you may be able to clarify.

Comment: The height of a tree isn't 1 plus the sum of heights of the subtrees. It should be 1 plus the max of the height of subtrees.

Comment: ahhh i get it. I was overthinking it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not handling an empty tree at all (unless your tree has a sentinel root node), and the height of a tree is not the sum of the subtrees' heights.

Also, these lines

```
int rHeight = 0;
int lHeight = 0;
if(n->right == NULL || n->left == NULL) return rHeight+lHeight+1;
```

are equivalent to

```
if(n->right == NULL || n->left == NULL) return 1;
```

which says that the height of a tree with only one subtree is 1, which would be incorrect even if it were supposed to count nodes.

You can do this with a one-liner:

```
int BTree::height(BSTNode *n) 
{
    return n == nullptr ? 0 : 1 + std::max(height(n->left), height(n->right));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a base case for null node and rest would work just fine.

```
int Solution::maxDepth(BSTNode* A) {
    if(A == NULL)
        return 0;
    return max(maxDepth(A->left) + 1, maxDepth(A->right) + 1);
}
```